# Using rails scope how to retrieve join tables and merge them

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails documentation there is this example in the scope section

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }
  scope :dry_clean_only, -> { joins(:washing_instructions).where('washing_instructions.dry_clean_only = ?', true) }
end
```

And in this example if I say Shirt.red I get a collection/queryset of all red Shirts. Also if I say dry_clean_only I get those ones. But if I say `Shirt.red.dry_clean_only` I assume this makes an `"AND"` connection and returns Shirts that are both red and dry_clean. How can I say, give me all Shirts that are either red or dry_clean. My concrete example is like this:

```
scope :in_title, -> (term) { where("title LIKE ?", "%#{term}%")}
scope :in_author, -> (term) { joins(:authors).where('first_name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%") }
```

I want to achieve:
`Book.in_title("Row").in_author("Row")` to return

```
[Book with title "Rows of olive trees", Book with author name "Rowling"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an `or` joining:

```
Book.in_title('Row').or(Book.in_author('Row'))
```

Now if you do this, you'll get an error that the queries do not match. For them to match, you'll need to join `author` also in the `in_title`.

Something like:

```
Book.joins(:authors).in_title('Row').or(Book.in_author('Row'))
```

Comment: @moddayjob cool ! also feel free to check PgSearch gem, it can handle the search in a better way with trigram and other search patterns / algorithms. -- other note: you need to mark the answer as `answer` when it's correct so people do not reply again

Comment: Yes it was just SO does not allow you for some time. I had to wait for it. I am doing a course about rails and I think so far I am not allowed to use external packages. But thanks for the advice!